# An error occured while processing the http request for the webDAV upload

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm uploading my app to Itunes. and im getting this error message

The failed to open ssh session always happens if some other issue occurs so im not worried about that. the other two i haven't seen before. The app does appear in itunes but its stuck in Processing. (over 24 hours)

Application Loader version 3.1(670)
Xcode 7.2.1 (7C1002) although im not going through XCODE im using Xamarin on current stable version

[image]

Comment: I would delete and re-upload.  Clearly something went wrong in the transfer.

Comment: I've a feeling it has something to do with the resources. Spent most of the day trying to figure out what's going on. I've rolled back to a previous version that i released with no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue just resolved it self this morning. I came into the office and the same ipa file and it went up without any issues. It might have been our the upload speed of our broadband dropping.